# Type of expression is ambiguous | SpringyCollectionViewFlowLayout

Tags: ios, iphone, swift2, uicollectionviewlayout

As described in this [UICollectionViewFlowlayout](https://github.com/CocoaHeadsBrasil/SwiftMagazine/blob/master/SwiftMagazine/SpringyFlowLayout.swift), Step 1:

```
// Need to overflow our actual visible rect slightly to avoid flickering.
var visibleRect = CGRectInset(self.collectionView!.bounds, -100, -100)
var itemsInVisibleRectArray: NSArray = super.layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(visibleRect)!
var itemsIndexPathsInVisibleRectSet: NSSet = NSSet(array: itemsInVisibleRectArray.valueForKey("indexPath") as [AnyObject])

// Step 1: Remove any behaviours that are no longer visible.
var noLongerVisibleBehaviours = (self.dynamicAnimator.behaviors as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(NSPredicate(block: {behaviour, bindings in
    var currentlyVisible: Bool = itemsIndexPathsInVisibleRectSet.member((behaviour as UIAttachmentBehavior).items.first!.indexPath) != nil
    return !currentlyVisible
}))
```

"Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" .. what should I do? I am really stuck :/

Thank you for any help I can get on this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone might just want to solve this problem, look here:

```
    let visibleRect = CGRectInset(self.collectionView!.bounds, -100, -100)
    let itemsInVisibleRect = super.layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(visibleRect)!
    let indexPathsInVisibleRect = Set(itemsInVisibleRect.map({ (attribute) -> NSIndexPath in
        return attribute.indexPath
    }))

    // Step 1: Remove any behaviours that are no longer visible.

    let noLongerVisisbleBehaviors = self.dynamicAnimator.behaviors.filter { (eachBehavior) -> Bool in
        var currentlyVisible = false
        if let behavior = eachBehavior as? UIAttachmentBehavior, first = behavior.items.first as? UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes {
            currentlyVisible = indexPathsInVisibleRect.contains(first.indexPath)
        }
        return !currentlyVisible
    }
```

Thankfully, this has proven to be a truly a huge save for the day :}